# Missing Project/Item Templates

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have Visual Studio 2010 and recently both at home and at work have had an issue with missing projects in the Installed Templates. All that projects and the folder called 'Data' is missing So now SQLDatabase, DataSet, AdoNet Entity Data Model, LinqToSQL, XMLFile, etc...

Fixes tried so far:

1. uninstall some recent framework addon or related products and it comes back.
2. The most common fix is to do 'devenv /installvstemplates' command which has not worked for me.
3. check for zip file in 
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Data\1033 folder and is contains all the appropriate zip files. Also the same for ItemTemplates folder.
4. Reinstall - Tried this 3 times no luck even went as far as to remove all reg keys and every folder that had anything to do with VS2010.
5. All complete reset of all VS2010 settings and other related commands.

I'm at a lose at what to do next. Beside a complete OS re-install which seems a little drastic. Anyone have a better solution please?

Comment: You probably do not have the correct version of Visual Studio.

Comment: what is the correct version of visual studio seeing how I'm ONLY running VS2010 on my computer can't see I couldn't be correct

Comment: There is posting here (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/8a5ae9e3-be7b-493d-831c-1e49e8103f26/) that mentions the IDE language setings affecting the templates. Worth looking at.

Answer (score 10):

Run `devenv.exe /installvstemplates` with elevated privileges

Comment: @Neurath: Strange. Worked for me.

Comment: it does work! here is the msdn page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241279(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: It worked for one item for me but not for trying to get the base level items back on the menu.   Not sure what the heck is missing but it is the same for 2 out of 3 installs for me.  gaaa

Comment: @Brian: Have you cleaned `ProjectTemplates` and `ItemTemplates` folders inside your VS installation?

Comment: yeah and all that did was remove all my templates.  Not sure what is going on now.

Comment: @Brian: Now run `/installvstemplates` again

Comment: Did that and it doesn't make a difference.  this is making me crazy

Comment: @Brian: Have you run that under admin privileges?

Comment: yep.   and tried it as InstallVSTemplates, installvstemplates, installVStemplates and about every other caps combinations.   weird thing is it did add the mvc3 template but I'm not getting the data option or templates

Comment: Strange... For me `devenv/InstallVSTemplates` worked, but `devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates` didn't...

Comment: @YanSklyarenko: Seem that you've run devenv.com which is located in the same folder and run by cmd before .exe

Comment: @abatishchev, Hmm, is it supposed to work the same way as .exe?

Comment: Make sure you run it for the appropriate version and also that you close any open instances of Visual Studio.

Comment: When I did this for VS 2017, it just displays another prompt immediately with no message either in the Cmd window or another pop-up one.  Also, when I ran "devenv.exe /?", it popped up a window that listed available command-line parameters, but the "/installvstemplates" parameter was not listed.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the .NET version at top of template list matches your solution's .NET version

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but with the `C#`code item templates, and I fixed it with the following:

```
Tools/Options/Environment/International Settings/Language:
                              "Same as Windows" instead of "English"
```

and then restart VS2010.

Comment: Now I noticed that when adding new item `Class` appears with all the items, but does not appear under `Code` category.

Comment: The opposit worked for me: Changed from "Same as Windows" to "English". Strange but true... Really want this solution multipe times up because its a really easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

I've just run into this issue and resolved it by doing the following:

1. I got the following folder and its contents from a colleague's PC \Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp.
2. Then I copied it to the appropriate location on my PC (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp)
3. I ran the command given in the answers above devenv.exe /installvstemplates using the Visual Studio Command Prompt tool with Administrator priviledges.

Comment: That worked for me! I was missing the BizTalk folder in both ProjectTemplates and ItemTemplates. Copying them from another machine did the trick :)