# Visual Studio 2010 - Silverlight 4 templates missing, how to redownload them?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, silverlight-4.0

I am missing the silverlight 4 templates for Visual Studio 2010. devenv /installvstemplate doesn't work because the actual files are missing, and the specific one I want (User Control) doesn't show up in the list of online templates. I've already tried the solutions in [Missing Project/Item Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780783/visual-studio-2010-missing-project-item-templates).

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ does not contain any project templates or item templates.

I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling all Silverlight components and tools I'm using.

Is there any way to just download the templates directly and put them in that folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the windows control panel, Programs and Features, and did a re-install of Visual Studio (VS lets you do that without having to uninstall and lose all your settings). After that, I re-instaled all the silverlight components I'm using. The templates are available now.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me: http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/05/06/missing-templates-in-visual-studio-installed-templates/

If you Close all instance of Visual Studio. Open visual studio command prompt and type,

**devenv /installvstemplates**

Press Enter