# Missing Local Database Cache Template in VS2012

Tags: database, caching, local, visual-studio-2012

I have a VS 2010 project that is based on the Local Database Cache template. Everything works great.

I want to write a similar project in VS2012, but I cannot find the same template. There is a "Local Database" template that uses SQL CE 4.0 exclusively, but even this does not display the required Configure Database Synchronization dialog.

Can anyone point me to where this template might be? (or has it been dropped from VS2012 and replaced by newer technology?)

Comment: I should add that other templates, like the project Windows Store template are also missing. I installed VS2012 after uninstalling VS2012RC.

Comment: I found this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780783/visual-studio-2010-missing-project-item-templates and followed the suggestions but this also made no difference. I have discovered that the Windows Store templates only appear if you are using a Windows 8 OS. (I'm still on Win 7). I have also discovered that there are no Database project templates, so I am thinking that this is effecting the lack of the Local Database Cache item template. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just found that it is a *BUG* in *Visual Studio 2012*, already submitted on *[Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/761198/visual-studio-2012-professional)*.