# Unable to find project template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, configuration

I just tried to create a Visual Studio 2010 project. However, when I tried to do so, I was presented with the following error message:

[image: Unable to find "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache\CSharp\Test\1033\TestProject.zip\TestProject.vstemplate". Please repair the product to fix this issue.]

I tried restarting Visual Studio, but this didn't help. I don't want to reinstall it if possible because I've installed a lot of extra stuff for it, and I don't want to spend the time reinstalling and reconfiguring it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2010 Missing Project/Item Templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780783/visual-studio-2010-missing-project-item-templates)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the file was missing from a cache since the path of the missing file contained the word `ProjectTemplatesCache`. I discovered that this cache folder had a parallel folder called `ProjectTemplates`. I was able to fix the problem by extracting `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Test\1033\TestProject.zip` into `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache\CSharp\Test\1033\TestProject.zip`.

I'm not sure what actually caused the problem, though.