# Visual studio (2012, 2013, 2015) missing setup and deployment templates

Tags: asp.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du13G.png)Today when I tried to add a setup project from Other Project Types templates, It shows me No items found. Then I click on teh Set up and Deployment link, it also shows me no items found.Using (VS 2012,2013,2015)

please help

Comment: I think u have not installed complete set up ...can u please share the screen print for VS....What all apps its showing ??

Comment: Thanks,See screenshot above.

Comment: Yes I am sure its not complete setup..

Comment: I treid this command and it did not help. Do you have any other ideas?
 
1. Go to Visual Studio Command Prompt:
2. Devenv /resetsettings  also
3. devenv.exe /installvstemplates

Comment: This command is used to open VS

Comment: Try this as well.....In Pro, they are under Other Project Types -> Setup and Deployment -> Visual Studio Installe

Comment: I treid this step but here error something like this :- Creating project 'setup'...project creation failed..

Comment: Please check this ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780783/missing-project-item-templates

Comment: One more ...http://www.fewlines4biju.com/2011/08/vs-2010-missing-setup-and-deployment.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Go to Visual Studio Command Prompt:
2. Devenv /resetsettings  also
3. devenv.exe /installvstemplates

Comment: I treid this command and it did not help. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

there should be a visual studio command prompt by going to start > all programs > visual studio  hover over it and u should see a command prompt for it. than type `devenv /resetsettings` also and than `devenv.exe /installvtemplates`
=) good luck`enter code here`